# (100% - fixed) works for div but not for button (Firefox and Opera issue)

Tags: css, layout, width

I'm trying to make two buttons, one with liquid width and the second with fixed width. And the method with `position: absolute` works fine for divs but not for buttons.

```
<menu class="sub">
    <button class="main">New</button>
    <button class="sub">+</button>
</menu>
<menu class="sub">
    <div class="main">New</div>
    <div class="sub">+</div>
</menu>
```

```css
menu.sub {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
menu.sub * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
menu.sub .main {
  right: 25px;
  width: auto;
}
menu.sub .sub {
  width: 25px;
  left: auto;
}
```

The div and the button look the same (I'm speaking about width only) in Chrome and IE, but the first button is minimum-width in Firefox and Opera. What's wrong with my code?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8nGH/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about making width 100%

```
menu.sub .main {
  right: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbaU2/)

Comment: You could do this, though you would have to give your + button a 1 or 2px border to have that separation

Comment: Thanks. However not right but added padding-right to have text centered.